# Is creating objects using CSV files a good practice?

Tags: java, android, csv, save

I am using Java to create an Android app. I have the main activity read a CSV file, create objects, and then save them into a singleton class so the rest of the activities in the app can access them easily.

This is working perfectly fine but I am not sure if there are some other ways to achieve the same result that are considered better practice, or if perhaps my solution could cause issues down the line that I am not aware of.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createItemObjects();
}


public void createItemObjects(){
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.items_csv);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    String line = "";
    try {
        while((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");
            String img = values[0];
            int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier(img , "drawable", getPackageName());
            items.add(new Item(imgID, values[1], values[2]));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("Main Activity", "Error Reading File on Line " + line, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ItemListHolder.getInstance().setItemsArrayList(items);
}
```

So as you can see, when the app launches it reads the CSV file, creates Item objects, creates an ArrayList to store those Item objects, then sends it into the ItemListHolder singleton, so that all the Activities in the app can use ItemListHolder.getInstance().getItemsArrayList() to retrieve the ArrayList of Item.

This works without any issues, but my question is: Is having your Android app create objects from a CSV file everytime it restarts considered good practice/safe to use/efficient ect, or should you be storing your objects in some other way, such as shared preferences, so that they are actually saved in memory and do not need to be created everytime the app launches and then held inside a class.

I am familiar with Java but am very new to android so I really have no idea what other ways of saving objects may or may not exist, or what is considered good to use.

Comment: (You might want to review [ask], as this is a bit off-topic for this site.) It's not immediately clear why you are doing this, but it sounds like some sort of configuration class that is instantiated with values from a file. You might want to show an example and tell us what you want to achieve with the singleton, and what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I am doing this to create an ArrayList of objects as soon as the app launches, let's say Items(containing int price, string name, ect),  that will be accessible by every activity in the app. Like I said what I am doing does work but I was just wondering if this is good practice for an android app or if it may cause a problem down the line. In other words, is creating objects using csv files considered good for android apps, or are there other ways to save and store objects that are better?

Comment: Again, maybe? It really depends on context. This site is not really good for what-if questions. There is a code review SE you could try maybe.

Comment: I mean, this isn't really a what-if question. Is it bad practice to have an app create your objects with a csv everytime it launches, or is it better to have the objects saved in some way like shared preferences?

Comment: Maybe posting your code would help.

Comment: If you are looking to save files for an Android app, you could read [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#java), from the Android docs, on how to save files to an Android device.

Comment: Is it bad practice? Probably a little weird for most Android developers. I'm not sure I'd call it bad practice, but it really depends on why you are doing this. I use Properties and persisted DAOs and whatnot depending on context and I also am on a special Android flavour where shared prefs are not good. If you are always deserializing classes like this and you have no other reasons to not do it, then there are Android specific ways of doing this. Again, any answer right now is "Maybe, but probably not, unless perhaps."

Comment: If your code is working, the question doesn't belong on StackOverflow.  Try asking again at [codereview.se].